# How to prevent Spring Security storing my custom UserDetails object in the session

Tags: spring, session, spring-security

I have configured Spring Security with a custom UserDetailsService and UserDetails implementation object that retrieve the user data from a JPA store.  However, the JPA-managed User object is then being stored in the HTTP session.  This causes a couple of problems:

- JPA-managed objects are expected to exist one-per-session, but this User object is being passed around all requests that the user initiates, potentially causing errors when lazy attributes are accessed, etc.  I've attempted to resolve this by trying to refresh the user object when it is requested from the UserDetailsService, but this doesn't seem entirely reliable, and doesn't prevent exceptions occurring in certain contexts (e.g. when the session is restored from a serialized copy at server startup).
- When the database is updated, the User object stored in the session is not changed to reflect the updates, causing out-of-date information to be returned in some circumstances.

I would like to simply store the user's ID in the session, and then resolve this to the actual User object on a per-request basis.  How can I do this?

My UserDetailsService looks like this:

```
@Service
public class JPAUserDetailsService implements org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService
{
    public static final Map<User.UserType,List<SimpleGrantedAuthority>> AUTHORITIES;

    static
    {
        AUTHORITIES = new HashMap<> ();
        AUTHORITIES.put (User.UserType.RESTRICTED, Arrays.asList (
            new SimpleGrantedAuthority ("PUBLIC"),
            new SimpleGrantedAuthority ("USER_PROFILE")));
        AUTHORITIES.put (User.UserType.NORMAL, Arrays.asList (
            new SimpleGrantedAuthority ("PUBLIC"),
            new SimpleGrantedAuthority ("USER_PROFILE"),
            new SimpleGrantedAuthority ("REGISTERED")));
        AUTHORITIES.put (User.UserType.ADMIN, Arrays.asList (
            new SimpleGrantedAuthority ("PUBLIC"),
            new SimpleGrantedAuthority ("USER_PROFILE"),
            new SimpleGrantedAuthority ("REGISTERED"),
            new SimpleGrantedAuthority ("ADMIN")));
    }

    public class UserWrapper implements UserDetails
    {
        User user;

        public UserWrapper (User user)
        {
            super ();
            this.user = user;
        }

        @Override
        public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities ()
        {
            return AUTHORITIES.get(user.getType ());
        }

        @Override
        public String getPassword ()
        {
            return user.getPassword ();
        }

        @Override
        public String getUsername ()
        {
            // the users canonical username (they may have multiple) is their most recent email address:
            return user.getEmailAddress ().stream ()
                    .sorted ((addr1, addr2) -> addr2.getValidFrom ().compareTo (addr1.getValidFrom ()))
                    .findFirst ()
                    .map (UserEmailAddress::getAddress)
                    .orElseGet (() -> user.getId ().toString ());
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isAccountNonExpired ()
        {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isAccountNonLocked ()
        {
            return ! user.isAccountLocked ();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired ()
        {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEnabled ()
        {
            return true;
        }

        public User getUser ()
        {
            User thisUser = user;
            if (!jpaContext.getEntityManagerByManagedType (User.class).contains (thisUser))
            {
                // user object needs refreshing for the current session
                thisUser = users.get (thisUser.getId ()).orElseThrow (
                    () -> new ConcurrencyFailureException ("User deleted from database during operation"));
                user = thisUser;
            }
            return thisUser;
        }
    }

    private JpaContext jpaContext;
    private UserRepository users;

    @Autowired
    public JPAUserDetailsService (UserRepository users, JpaContext jpaContext)
    {
        this.users = users;
        this.jpaContext = jpaContext;       
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername (String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException
    {
        return users.findByCurrentEmailAddress (username)
            .map (UserWrapper::new)
            .orElseThrow (() -> new UsernameNotFoundException (username));
    }

    public UserDetails wrap (User u)
    {
        return new UserWrapper(u);
    }


}
```

### Updated

Writing up the process Spring uses for handling authentication in response to a comment below, I figured I should place my notes of how this works into here, because it might help somebody else figure out what I'm missing.  My understanding of the process I'm trying to modify is this:

- When somebdoy logs in to my site, the login form submission is intercepted by the Spring Security filter, and my `UserDetailsService` implementation (a regular, singleton-scoped Spring bean) is invoked to fetch a `UserDetails` object corresponding to the entered username.  The password is checked, and if it matches the login filter creates a [`UsernamePassworkAuthenticationToken`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.html) and invokes [`SecurityContext.setAuthentication`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/context/SecurityContext.html#setAuthentication-org.springframework.security.core.Authentication-) in the current request's security context.  The HTTP security context implementation ends up storing the token in the HTTP session object.

The obvious solution to this doesn't work.  Changing the `UserDetails` object to store the `User` object's ID field and fetch it on demand fails because the HTTP session requires all objects placed within it to be `Serializable` (and in fact may arbitrarily serialize and deserialize them without notice, e.g. during a server reconfiguration or for migration between two nodes in a load balancing system), and the ability to fetch a `User` depends on a reference to a Spring-configured `UserRepository` instance, that I have no reasonable way of fetching in a static context: I can only create a valid `UserDetails` under circumstances where I can control the available instance data, so that I can ensure the correct `UserRepository` is available.

This suggests that there is a possible alternative solution to this, which may be more generic than finding a way to get Spring Security to recreate the UserDetails object on demand: is there a way of storing objects in the HTTP session such that when they are deserialized by the container, associations to Spring service beans such as my `UserRepository` instance can be reconnected during deserialization?

Comment: "I would like to simply store the user's ID in the session, and then resolve this to the actual User object on a per-request basis",  this is what is known as request scope, so I think if you add `@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)` to your service, it can do the trick.

Comment: @zakariaamine - won't that create a UserDetailsService instance per request, rather than a UserDetails object?

Comment: Yes it will. UserDetails is not a bean, so it will not be affected.

Comment: ... but it's the UserDetails I need to change the behaviour of, not the UserDetailsService.

Comment: sorry I did not see the `@Autowired` on UserDetails, yes you can use that on `UserDetails` as well

Comment: @zakariaamine - the `UserDetails` isn't autowired.  It's returned by `UserDetailsService.loadByUsername`, which is called by Spring Security's login processor when I submit a login request.  The resulting `UserDetails` object is then stored in the security context by creating a `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` that is passed to `SecurityContext.setAuthentication`; the `SecurityContext` is then directly storing the token in the HTTP session object, which is the behaviour I'm trying to change.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very interesting questions. I also stumbled over the same problem.

You may store any information with your custom implementation of spring's `UserDetails`. This may be your own custom "UserEntity". This may also only be an ID or for example a JsonWebToken (JWT).

**Out-of-time data**: I would say that this is not a big problem. The UserDetails is reloaded for every request. Since requests are normally responded very quickly, within seconds, this should normally not be a problem.

**JPA-managed-object**: Yes there may be several instances of your own UserEntity flying around in different sessions. Especially when your system is under high load. But from a JPA/Hibernate view they are all detached entities. So no worries here.

==> **EXCEPT** <==

When you have LAZY loaded attributes in your UserEntity. This **is** a problem. You cannot load them. At least I didn't find a way yet.